# Coding iOS app with Phonegap and Django

Tags: django, cordova

I am trying to write an iOS app with phone gap. I want to use Django to code the backend. May I know if it's possible to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible. using AJAX you can call your backend service, and it doesn't matter how you implement it as long as in the bottom line it can handle requests (and probably return JSON/XML)

Comment: Thanks. I should start play with ajax.